# How to check if a particular image exists inside an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I want to know that if a particular image rest inside an imageview.

Something like this

```
if(imagevew.getImage()==R.drawable.image1){
//do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getConstantState()` method of drawable return a `Drawable.ConstantState` instance that holds the shared state of this drawable.

```
if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1).getConstantState()) {
      Toast.makeText(_con, "Image is image1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
     Toast.makeText(_con, "Image isn't image1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); \
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this:

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.img);
String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(v.getTag());    

if( backgroundImageName.equals(ImageName))
{
   //do something
} 
else{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward answer here , you can do something like settag when doing the setresource that way you'll know the name of the resource ,

something like :

```
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.drawablename);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawablename);
String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(imageView.getTag());
```

and than do a check like :

```
if (backgroundImageName.equals("BG"))  // "BG" is the tag that you set previously
    {
      Toast.makeText(_con, "Image is ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
  else 
    {
     Toast.makeText(_con, "Image isn't ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
```